# Expressing partial decidability using existential quantification

Tags: computability

**def.**
A predicate M(x,y) is *partially decidable* if the function f given by " f(x,y) = 1(if M(x,y) holds), f(x,y) = undefined(otherwise) " is computable.

**Thm.**
If M(x,y) is partially decidable, then so is the predicate ∃yM(x,y).

proof.
 Take a decidable predicate R(x,y,z) such that M(x,y) iff ∃zR(x,y,z).
Then...

---

I can not imagine the R(x,y,z)...
Please explain the way of thinking.

( Page115, Computability by Nigel Cutland)

Comment: How do you define partially decidable?

Comment: Please edit your question to include explanation of "partially decidable" (and delete comment afterwards). Please include more accessible reference (I do not know what resource the "Cutland p115" is).

Answer (score 1):

The predicate $R(x,y,z)$ states that "$M$ accepts the input $x,y$ within $z$ steps". It is computable since we can simulate a given machine on a given input for a bounded number of steps.

Comment: See also [Kleene's $T$ predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_T_predicate).